# Question about implementing label setting/correction/dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

For those of you that familiar with this algorithm. My question is, how do you code the part of getting efficient subset with dynamic programming? I understand the logic, but just couldn't put it into code, because the label dimension is usually pretty high, how do you implement it without writing 10s or maybe 100s of nested 'for' loops?

For those of you that are not familiar with this algorithm. My question is, how to you find the biggest subset with non dominant tuples. we say tuple A dominants tuple B, if all elements inside tuple A are smaller than the ones in tuple B, `B[0] < A[0] & B[1] < A[1] & B[2] < A[2] & ...`. And such tuples like B should be removed from the set.

For example, considering the set of tuples below

> (1, 7, 1, 5, 2), (6, 2, 3, 3, 2), (5, 5, 6, 9, 8), (2, 4, 9, 9, 7), (4, 1, 2, 8, 7), (3, 0, 2, 0, 2), (5, 1, 1, 1, 3), ...

(3, 0, 2, 0, 2) dominates (6, 2, 3, 3, 2), (5, 5, 6, 9, 8), (4, 1, 2, 8, 7)

How do you program this without writing 5 nested for loops? If I write it with recursion, then there would be a lot of repetitive computations, but if I use iterations, then, I would need a 5 dimension array to save the result.

Comment: What is the "this algorithm" that you refer to? Given a set of *n* *k*-tuples, it's straightforward to get the maximal subset of dominating tuples in O(n²k) time without using dynamic programming and without running into the problem you describe. Is there a faster algorithm that you're trying to implement that runs into this problem?

Comment: @ruakh I don't know if I calculate it correctly, if every element in the tuple can take value [0 - 9], then, n could be as big as 10 to the power of 5, lets say n is 10^4, then, the brute force would take 10^4 * 10^4, which has higher time complexity than dynamic programming 10^5

Comment: Oh, I think I see the algorithm you have in mind. But in that case it's odd to talk about "10s or maybe 100s of nested 'for' loops", because 10^100 is much more than the number of atoms in the observable universe. Even just 2^100 is much more than the number of bits stored on all the computers in the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your concern is that you'll have an *n*-dimensional array *A*, where you need the following operations:

- You need to iterate over array elements in such a way that you don't visit *A*[*i*<sub>0</sub>][*i*<sub>1</sub>][…][*i*<sub>*n*−1</sub>] until after you've visited its predecessor along each dimension (*A*[*i*<sub>0</sub>−1][*i*<sub>1</sub>][…][*i*<sub>*n*−1</sub>], *A*[*i*<sub>0</sub>][*i*<sub>1</sub>−1][…][*i*<sub>*n*−1</sub>], …, and *A*[*i*<sub>0</sub>][*i*<sub>1</sub>][…][*i*<sub>*n*−1</sub>−1]).
- When visiting *A*[*i*<sub>0</sub>][*i*<sub>1</sub>][…][*i*<sub>*n*−1</sub>], you need to examine its predecessor along each dimension.

and you're worried that the only way to do this is to have separate variables for each of *i*<sub>0</sub>, *i*<sub>1</sub>, …, and *i*<sub>*n*−1</sub>, and have a for-loop for each one.

(Part of your concern seems excessive to me — you mention "10s or maybe 100s of nested 'for' loops", but you can't store 2<sup>100</sup> elements anyway, that's more than all the data in all the computers on Earth — but even five nested for-loops is messy and error-prone, and of course then you're tied to a specific number of dimensions. So, it's reasonable to not want to do that.)

You can solve this by representing your "logical" *n*-dimensional array as an "underlying" *one*-dimensional array with the appropriate number of elements, using an array of integers as your "logical" index, and writing logic to map between that array and an "underlying" index that's a single integer.

For example, if your "logical" array *A* is 10×10×10×10×10, then you can create a single "underlying" array `A` of length 10<sup>5</sup>, and the element at "logical" position [3,4,5,6,7] — meaning *A*[3][4][5][6][7] — is `A[34_567]`. Here's a Java method that converts from the former to the latter:

```
public int getUnderlyingIndex(
    final int[] index,
    final int[] dimensions
) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int dim = 0; dim < dimensions.length; ++dim) {
        result = result * dimensions[dim] + index[dim];
    }
    return result;
}
```

For iteration purposes, you need a function to "increment" the index — for example, given [1,2,3,9,9] it would change it to [1,2,4,0,0] — and let you know if you've passed the end of the array. Here's what that might look like in Java:

```
public boolean incrementIndexArray(
    final int[] index,
    final int[] dimensions
) {
    int dim = index.length - 1;
    while (true) {
        index[dim]++;
        if (index[dim] < dimensions[dim]) {
            return true; // iteration can continue
        }
        index[dim] = 0;
        --dim;
        if (dim < 0) {
            return false; // done iterating
        }
    }
}
```

For purposes of checking the predecessors of an element, you can write a single for-loop.  Here's what that might look like in Java:

```
for (int dim = 0; dim < dimensions.length; ++dim) {
    if (index[dim] == 0) {
        // no predecessor along this dimension
        continue;
    }
    index[dim]--;
    final int predecessor =
        underlyingArray[getUnderlyingIndex(index)];
    index[dim]++;
    // ... do what you want with it ...
}
```